# http request at page load even with display none

Tags: css, html

```
<div style="display: none;">
<img src="mypic.jpg" alt="My photo">
</div>
```

Even though I have 'display:none' at the parent container (the div tag), why would the image would initiate a http request at page load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It initiates a http request because `display: none` only hides the content, but the image is still on page, You need to add the image dynamically by JavaScript according to your requirement/condition.

Comment: isn't that something visibilily:hidden does?

Comment: Neither prevent the content from loading. visibility and hidden just differ in whether the rest of the content is re-flowed when the element is hidden.

Comment: Hidden still reserves the space on the page. Display none means it is not rendered at all...

Answer (score 1):

`display: none` refer to the user interface, while the `<img />` tag perform the http request when the tag is rendered in the html.

Comment: The `<img>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: @RobC This isn't XHTML.

Comment: @RobC I was responding to the "and never has.", xhtml used to be big, think that counts as "has". Not going to nitpick anymore. Think the robs can bury the hatchet ;) Cheers!

Comment: @RobC HTML **never has** had a closing slash on the `<img>` tag. Period. End of story. And you will not find any HTML specificatioin in the history of HTML that shows it, even as an example.